# Are there any UK domain registrars that support .at domain names?

Tags: domain-registration

Are there any UK domain registrars that support .at domain names? I've registered a .at domain and would like to move it to a UK registrar.

If not, which registrar would you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Turns out 123 Reg don't support .at domains although their marketing and sales waffle suggests they do.

---

[123 reg](http://www.123-reg.co.uk) support .at domains

https://www.123-reg.co.uk/domain-names/cheap-domain-names.shtml

Comment: You have to scroll down to "Europe - popular" and click the "Show more" link to see .at domains in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

I've just done a "Global search" at http://www.names.co.uk/ and .at domains are shown as available there.

They're also shown in the price list: http://www.names.co.uk/pricelist.html

(It's probably worth mentioning I work there, but I don't get commission :))

Comment: Can you vouch for names.co.uk. Have you used them?

Comment: Not for a .at, but I do have a .eu with them.